# How do I serve an HTML file in Express from a directory which is a level above my server folder?

Tags: javascript, express, server, filepath

I am trying to serve an HTML file which is in my main directory, through my Express server which is one level deeper: in my server folder. This is how the server code is set up:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}.`))
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/mnt/c/Project-Directory/server/index.html'
```

It is clear from this error why I am not able to access my HTML file; my server exists in the /server folder and my index.html file exists in the Project-Directory folder. However, I am not sure how to access my HTML file in its current directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [path.join](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathjoinpaths) and specify that you want one directory back (`../`):

```
const path = require('path');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../index.html'));
})
```